# Slip joint nut leaks at PVC-copper joint in sink drain pipe

Tags: leak, drainage

The 1.5 in PVC-copper slip nut joint (red arrow in the picture below) is leaking (slow drip) from the lower part of the joint.

I've tried taken them apart and replace the red rubber gasket, cleaned the PVC pipes, and hand tighten the white cap. However, it's still dripping.

Does it need more cleaning on of the copper, or I need to replace the joint altogether?

It's my first post here. Thank you all in advance for the help!

[[image: PVC-copper slip nut joint with rubber gasket]]
[image: Zoom out view of the pipes under the sink]

Comment: Best guess is the white nut is hitting the bronze nut before getting tight enough.  When tighten is there any space(even paper thickness) between the white and bronze pieces?

Comment: It doesn't look square & the black soft seal doesn't look like it goes far enough in; hasn't hit the sealing rings yet -https://i.stack.imgur.com/YClC4.png Will it push in tighter first, before you screw it up? …and, as I noticed later…  far more importantly …what is it screwing onto? I can't see anywhere the white nut is supposed to go, there's an ugly old iron nut right where it needs to fasten up, which has to come off first… then you can hope the threads match.

Comment: @Tetsujin  The old iron nut looks to be a reducer fitting, so probably no adjustment except replacing.

Comment: Was it like that before or did you install a new pipe? I think what @crip659 suggested should be checked out.

Comment: The threads on the white plastic and metal piece do not look like they match either.  The metal threads look finer than the plastic.

Comment: @crip659 The white nut seems to touch the bronze nut. Would it help to put some padding in the white nut (e.g., another gasket on top of existing gasket) to force a tight seal?  I'm going to try that in a few days when I get back from my trip. Thanks so much for the great hypothesis.

Comment: Think the bronze nut reducer needs to be changed.  The threads do not seem to match each other and adding extra gaskets usually cause more problems in time.  Would remove the bronze reducer and take it and a section of the white pipe/nut to a plumbing place/shop to get the proper piece.  If the threads don't match, it will leak in time, even with an extra gasket.

Comment: I still can see no purpose at all for the metal nut. If the black ribbed bit we can see is a thread & not just a ribbed insert seal, then what's holding it in place? The white nut isn't. The metal nut isn't. If it is a ribbed seal, then it needs pushing hard into the metal pipe & the white nut tightening onto the metal threaded pipe to squeeze the two together. Seeing the section disassembled might give more clues.